# Laravel 8 onde armazenar minhas ACCESS_KEY de API's?

Tags: laravel, variáveis-de-ambiente, api-key

Não sei onde no LARAVEL 8 eu poderia adicionar minhas *ACCESS_KEY's* das *API's* que estou construindo como portfolio.

Ex:
Estou realizando alguns testes com uma API `https://currencylayer.com/documentation` e já adquiri minha *acess_key* para obter uma request, mas esse projeto estará no *github* como publico e não gostaria de publicar com minha key pessoal, onde eu poderia adiciona-la no *laravel* para não ser publicada no *github*, **SERA QUE NO *.ENV* DARIA CERTO?**

E depois de armazena-la **como eu poderia realizar uma chamada para ela compor minha URL completa?**

EX: de REQUEST COMPLETO

```
http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=**67fb2adasd5b4bfe55cb62097ff2fd**&currencies=BRL&source=USD&format=1
```

RETORNO do REQUEST:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1649664723,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDBRL":4.696298
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro um direcionamento, é ideal que faça as perguntas em separado, mesmo que pareçam estar no mesmo contexto.

Respondendo a primeira, sim, o `.env` é o melhor local, até por quê você não deve versionar no repositório este arquivo, e poderá ter configurações diferentes para a mesma chave em ambientes diferentes.

Outra sugestão aqui seria criar um arquivo de configuração, talvez chamado `config/currency_layer.php`, com o seguinte código:

```php
<?php 
   
  return [
     "key" => env("CURRENCY_LAYER_KEY"), 
  ];
```

E no `.env` adiciona uma chave com o nome: `CURRENCY_LAYER_KEY`

Para a segunda pergunta vou dar um exemplo para montar uma variável do tipo string que será passada para o mecanismo que estiver usando para fazer o request (Guzzle, cUrl, etc).

```php
$url = "http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" . config("currency_layer.key") . "&currencies=BRL&source=USD&format=1
```

Comment: Ademir Muito obrigado pelas dicas, inclusive sobre as perguntas, mas me ajudou muito.